# A discontinuous function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ satisfying: for each closed ball $B$ of $Y, f^{-1}(B)$ is closed in $X$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, advice

Find a function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ between metric spaces $X$ and $Y$ that is not continuous but has the property that for each closed ball $B$ of $Y, f^{-1}(B)$ is closed in $X$

**Solution Attempt:**

A continuous function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is defined as : For every open set $V$ in $Y$, there's an open set $U \in X$ such that $f(U) \subseteq V$.

**Strategy:** The issue with closed sets while defining continuity can be that a closed set $U_o \in X $ can also contain limit points which may not get mapped to the closed set $V_o$.

**EDIT:** Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a an identity function where $X$ is a non-discrete metric space and $Y$ is a metric space with the discrete metric. (As far as it's set elements were concerned, $X$=$Y$..)So, $f(x) = x ~\forall x \in X$. $X$ is non discrete metric space $\implies$ there is atleast one subset of $X$ which is closed but not open in $X$. Could you please explain how these arguments tell us that $f^{-1}(x_{|Y}) = x_{|X}$  is closed in $X$? . Thank you!

Comment: If you endow $Y$ with the discrete metric, the balls have a particularly simple structure.

Comment: If $f^{-1}(B) \subseteq X$ were closed for _any_ closed set $B \subseteq Y$, then the function is continuous. So you need to make sure that there are many closed sets that aren't balls. As Daniel Fischer points out in the above comment, putting the discrete metric (all distances that aren't $0$ are $1$) on $Y$ works nicely.

Comment: Interesting (at least for me) side question: Can we stil find a counter example if we insist on $Y=\Bbb{R}^d$ with the usual Euclidean metric? At least any such function will be Borel measurable, but is it continuous?

Comment: @PhoemueX Any function with a closed graph has this property, and those don't have to be continuous (e.g., $f(x)=1/x$ extended by $f(0)=0$).

Comment: @NormalHuman: Thank you very much!

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you for answering. I understand that the only closed balls of the discrete metric will be the singleton sets and $Y$ itself. But, what makes the pre-image of the singleton sets closed in $X$? Thanks again!

Comment: @Arthur thanks for your reply. but why should the pre-image of the closed balls in $Y, ~(Y $ being a discrete metric space $)$ be closed sets? thanks again!

Comment: "But, what makes the pre-image of the singleton sets closed in $X$?" Simply define the function that way! Just make sure that in your example there's at least one closed set (not a closed ball) in $Y$ such that $f^{-1}(Y)$ is not closed.

Comment: "but why should the pre-image of the closed balls in $Y$ [...] be closed sets?" Because the problem tells you that that's the case. You are supposed to find / construct two metric spaces $X,Y$ and a function $f:X\to Y$ such that the preimage of any closed ball in $Y$ is closed, but where there are closed sets in $Y$ whose preimage is not closed. That's exactly what the problem says (if you use the rephrasing from my first comment).

Comment: Whether the preimages of singletons are closed depends on $X$ and $f$ of course. But if $f$ is injective, the preimage of a singleton is either a singleton or empty, thus closed (since $X$ shall be a metric space, and singletons are closed in $T_1$-spaces). And that makes it easy to find such an $f$. Let $X$ be any non-discrete metric space, $Y$ the same set, but endowed with the discrete metric, and $f$ the identity.

Comment: @DanielFischer Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a an identity function where $X$ is a non-discrete metric space and $Y$ is a metric space with the discrete metric. So, $f(x) = x ~\forall x \in X$. $X$ is non discrete metric space $\implies$ there is atleast one subset of $X$ which is closed but not open. Could you please explain how these arguments tell us that $f^{-1}(x_{|Y}) = x_{|X}$  is closed in $X$? . Thank you!

Comment: $f^{-1}(\{x\}) = \{x\}$ in that situation, and singleton sets (more generally finite sets) are closed in every metric space (every $T_1$ space even). And $f^{-1}(Y) = X$ is always closed. So if $Y$ is endowed with the discrete metric, so that all balls are either singletons or the whole space, the preimage of every closed ball is closed.

Comment: @DanielFischer Many thanks for your comments. May I please request you to also have a look here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3343110/difference-between-continuity-and-uniform-continuity-on-union-of-sets . Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer the question you have asked as per your edit.

Let $f:(X,d)\to(X,\rho)$ be the identity map $f(x)=x$, where $\rho$ is the discrete metric and $d$ is any non-discrete metric.

**Claim 1:** The only closed balls in $(X,\rho)$ are singletons and the full space.

*Proof:* Let $x\in X$ and $r>0$. Let $\bar{B}_r(x)$ be the closed ball centered at $x$ of radius $r$. It is easy to see that if $r<1$ then $\bar{B}_r(x)=\{x\}$ and if $r\ge1$ then $\bar{B}_r(x)=X$. This proves the claim.

**Claim 2:** Inverse image of closed balls in $(X,\rho)$ are closed in $(X,d)$.

*Proof:* Clearly $f^{-1}(X)=X$ is closed in $(X,d)$. Next consider $f^{-1}(x)=\{x\}$. We will show that $\{x\}$ is closed in $(X,d)$ by showing that its complement $X\setminus\{x\}$ is open.
Let $y\in X\setminus\{x\}$. Let $r=d(x,y)$. The open ball $B_{r/2}(y)$ does not contain $x$ and hence lies entirely in $X\setminus\{x\}$. Thus  $X\setminus\{x\}$ is open which gives us $\{x\}$ is closed. This proves the claim.

**Claim 3:** The function $f$ is not continuous.

*Proof:* Since $(X,d)$ is not discrete, there is one subset of $X$ that is not open. We can assume without loss of generality that this set is a singleton say, $\{y\}$ (for otherwise every set would be open being the union of singletons). Let $V=\{y\}$, then $V$ is open in $(X,\rho)$. However, there is no non-empty open set $U$ in $(X,d)$ such that $f(U)\subset V=\{y\}$ (the only possibility for $U$ would have been $\{y\}$ which is not open). This proves the claim.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**Counterexample**:

$f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=\ln(x)$ if $x>0$ and $f(0)=0$ is not continuous at $0$ but inverse image of any closed ball in $\mathbb R$ is closed in $[0,\infty)$ but $f^{-1}(-\infty,-1]=(0,1/e]$ which is not closed in $X=[0,\infty)$.